# cts:Query from sem:SPARQL

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

How can I create a cts:query from sem:sparql…

Background, I am tyring create a custom constraint, and for that it needs to return cts:query.. but in my custom constraint I want to do sparql.. how do I do this..
eg:

```
sem:sparql("select DISTINCT ?subject  
            from 
           <http://rdf.abbvienet.com/entity/abbvie/biologic> 
           where {?subject <http://schemas.abbvienet.com/entity/target> <http://rdf.abbvienet.com/entity/ncbi/target/695>} ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out .. need to use `cts:triple-range-query`

If anyone is interested.. following is what I did for my eg sparq above..

```
  cts:and-query((cts:triple-range-query((), sem:iri('http://schemas.abbvienet.com/entity/target'), 
                                                              sem:iri('http://rdf.abbvienet.com/entity/ncbi/target/695')),
                                   cts:collection-query('http://rdf.abbvienet.com/entity/abbvie/biologic'))))
```

Please let me know if there is nicer way to do this :) ?

Comment: The and-query for the collection-query is probably too restrictive. I'd probably do something like `cts:triple-range-query(sem:sparql(...) ! map:get(., "subject"))`. If you need more complex joins between sparql, views, and cts lexicon, Optic API might be interesting too..